# Need help finding a value in this string with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have this string:
`<div class="details"><label>Contract Size | Price</label><span title="DayVol: 114,102  / OI: 9,239">600 @ 1.21</span></div>`

I'm looking to find this value 600 @ 1.21

This value changes, can someone help me find a way to get it dynamically?

Comment: Add to question: What version of powershell. Give three more examples of the value.

Comment: If my answer works for your please mark as solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using regex. I'm not the best at regex so it may need modified.

```
$string=@"
<div class="details"><label>Contract Size | Price</label><span title="DayVol: 114,102  / OI: 9,239">600 @ 1.21</span></div>
"@

$regex = "(?<=\>)\d.*[ ][@][ ]\d.*[.]\d.*(?=\</span>)"

$string -match $regex
$myValue = $matches[0]
```

I'm looking for any NUMBERofanylength-space-@-spaceNUMBERofanylength-Period-NUMBERofanylength that preceeds a `</span>` tag. This will work if there are no other similar strings in your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string as an XML document in PowerShell and then navigate through the elements:

```
PS C:\Users\Luke> $xmlstring = '<div class="details"><label>Contract Size | Price</label><span title="DayVol: 114,102  / OI: 9,239">600 @ 1.21</span></div>';
PS C:\Users\Luke> echo ([xml]$xmlstring).div.span.'#text'
600 @ 1.21
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input will always be valid xml, you could parse it and extract the value as follows:

```bsh
$input = @"
<div class="details"><label>Contract Size | Price</label><span title="DayVol: 114,102 / OI: 9,239">600 @ 1.21</span></div>
"@

$xml = [xml] $input

$value = $xml.div.span.innertext

$value # 600 @ 1.21
```

You could convert this to a one-liner if you wanted to, but it’s a bit clearer what it’s doing as multiple steps...

Comment: Natch. Beaten by 3 minutes by @luke Woodward. About the same length of time as it takes to type backtick code fences on an iPhone :-).